# Django and venv: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value

Tags: django, virtualenv

This happens when I run python manage.py syncdb.  It also happens when I run python manage.py syncdb --mysite.settings.  Not sure where to go from here: django isn't recognizing my settings file and I don't know why or how to rectify it.

```
python ../manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ryan/Programming/OpenCV-2.4.2/msheroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ryan/Programming/OpenCV-2.4.2/msheroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ryan/Programming/OpenCV-2.4.2/msheroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/ryan/Programming/OpenCV-2.4.2/msheroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ryan/Programming/OpenCV-2.4.2/msheroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/ryan/Programming/OpenCV-2.4.2/msheroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/home/ryan/Programming/OpenCV-2.4.2/msheroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 15, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

From settings.py

```
DATABASES = { 
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'xxx',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'xxx',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }   
}
```

I'm pretty confident that it's not finding the right settings file to begin with.

Comment: Can you post the db config in your settings.py?

Comment: So, is your `settings.DATABASES` properly configured?

Answer (score 4):

Hi I am assuming you are testing your app using heroku and your trying to connect to your local database ? if so be sure to remove this line of code :

```
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
  import dj_database_url
  DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
  SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

Add it in when you are gonna connect to a database on a anther server.

Comment: How about being able to use both HEROKU and Local DB?

Comment: @mgPePE Have a settings-local.py and settings-production.py file. Then when you are running locally type                                python manage.py --settings=appname.settings-local

Answer (score 0):

A correct one would look something like this.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost', # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Edit: changed host to localhost to reflect comments & manage.py

Based on how your running your syncdb

```
python manage.py syncdb --mysite.settings
```

Make sure your manage.py file has the correct DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE specified

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

You should then be able to run syncdb without --mysite.settings

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Comment: Specifically the **'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'**

Comment: @camelCase you have mentioned about virtualenv. Hod did you create it, how are you running it? What Django version are you using? Empty string for localhost it's OK. Like Nathaniel says, you should change ENGINE

Comment: @CésarBustíos empty string for localhost is NOT universally OK. From the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/

If you're using PostgreSQL, by default (empty HOST), the connection to the database is done through UNIX domain sockets ('local' lines in pg_hba.conf). If you want to connect through TCP sockets, set HOST to 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' ('host' lines in pg_hba.conf). On Windows, you should always define HOST, as UNIX domain sockets are not available.

Comment: @LimH. Thanks I didn't know that. I guess I've never had trouble before since I never use PostgreSQL or Windows :)

Comment: I don't think I would be getting a 'please supply the engine value' error if it was looking at this settings file, which is why I don't think it's looking at the right file.  I did change ENGINE to django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 and got the same error message.  I created my virtualenv by virtualenv venv --distribute then source venv/bin/activate to activate it.

Comment: If you put a print statement in your settings file you could at least see if it's being loaded.

Comment: What does your manage.py file say os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "somepackage.settings")

Comment: the print statement executed, and "mysite.settings"

Comment: Is the DATABASE redefined in either the same file or a local_settings.py file?

Comment: That was the problem!  For heroku, I have import dj_database_url
#DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()